# Limitation of developing android apps in qt

Tags: android, qt, sdk, android-ndk

I have developed Qt based application on linux platform.

Then same thing ported in windows also it working fine.

Recently I have ported in android, it is working fine but i want know the limitations of using Qt for android app development.

Is it possible to integrate third party component which in developed in java in QT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every platform has there pro and cons.
Beside native coding there are many cross platform for android like Ionic,PhoneGap,React Native and QT so cross platform is improving rapidly but it has it's own limitation for some functionality.In cross platform i like React Native myself because it provide the native functionality.

Now what platform you are selecting , you have to look what platform provides what e.g Ionic provide style like iPhone and using angular Js which make it quite an option to select iPhone for making fast and iPhone style app

native is always on step ahead,with cross platform you can develop something but in native you can develop everything.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate third party component which in developed in java in QT?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052887/native-using-java-functions-3rd-party-libraries-in-qt-for-android